# How can we write a custom ObjectInspector in Hive for a custom Writable type?

Tags: hadoop, hive, udf

I am trying to write a custom writable type for a complex object type - to control the serialization and de-serialization.

And I want to create a ObjectInspector for that, i tried to find out an example for the same. But no suitable example is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to write a custom ObjectInspector for this. Have you tried to implement it as a custom SerDe? Checkout [this blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-a-serde-in-apache-hive/) from Cloudera for more details.

If you're curious about how to implement custom ObjectInspectors, you can checkout an example of [ProtobufStructObjectInspector](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird/blob/master/hive/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/hive/serde/ProtobufStructObjectInspector.java) from Elephant Bird.

**EDIT:** Added an example of ObjectInspector implementation for posterity.

Comment: Thanks @Pradeep for prompt response, actually SerDe will not work in my case because i am trying to introduce a custom writable type (WritableGeometry) that can be used by both - MapReduce jobs and Hive UDF. But SerDe  is for hive not for MapReduce.

Comment: But I am not sure that should i create a ObjectInspector for that or not. I just want to make sure in initialize() method of GenericUDF that I am getting a correct ObjectInspector.